# subprocess.Popen returns pid that doesn't exists - windows 10

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess

I am trying to open a process, wait few minutes and then close it.
I am using windows 10, and python 3.7. When using subprocess.Popen the program opens fine, but when I try to close to using multiple options none works.
It seems that proc.pid doesn't hold valid PID, so no matter how I try to close it, nothing works. Any idea what to do?

```
import subprocess
import signal
import os
import time
import psutil

def kill_proc_tree(pid, including_parent=True):
    parent = psutil.Process(pid)
    children = parent.children(recursive=True)
    for child in children:
        child.kill()
    gone, still_alive = psutil.wait_procs(children, timeout=5)
    if including_parent:
        parent.kill()
        parent.wait(5)

def kill_child_processes(parent_pid, sig=signal.SIGTERM):
    try:
      parent = psutil.Process(parent_pid)
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
      return
    children = parent.children(recursive=True)
    for process in children:
      process.send_signal(sig)

proc = subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome_proxy.exe",
                  '--profile-directory=Default',
                  '--app-id=asdbiflszpsdsdn'])

time.sleep(5)
os.kill(proc.pid, signal.SIGTERM) #or signal.SIGKILL
proc.terminate()
proc.kill()
kill_proc_tree(proc.pid, True)
kill_child_processes(proc.pid)
os.killpg(proc.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
subprocess.Popen("taskkill /F /T /PID %i"%proc.pid , shell=True)

os.kill(proc.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: `chrome_proxy` almost immediately launches `chrome`, which probably launches or communicates with another instance of `chrome` itself.  That is to say, the process you started is a small worker that does it's job and ends almost the instant you launch it.

Comment: How do you know subprocess.popen() succeeded?  Can you  check it?  Shouldn't you?   Also, is the `[r"` a typo, or a python thing?

Comment: also, the program name contains a space, does that need to be escaped?  How do you escape things for windows, since they use the escape character for a path separator?   Can you make the program not be in a weird directory just to be sure?